# How to build PHP bindings for Xapian on Raspbian

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, xapian

Am trying to build PHP bindings for Xapian on Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi

Following instructions here

http://trac.xapian.org/wiki/FAQ/PHP%20Bindings%20Package

I am falling at the second hurdle!

```
sudo apt-get build-dep xapian-bindings
```

gives me the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
```

I have tried adding deb-src entries to /etc/apt/sources.list and the 3 files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d

i.e.

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
deb-src http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having added the repositories to the sources.list, you must then do

```
sudo apt-get update
```

for the new sources to be available.

Comment: Doh! Yep, just needed to re-run step 1 as I only added the deb-src's after step 2 failed.